# HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate() returns null in Web API

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, iis-express

I have a .NET4.5 WebAPI 2 app that uses SSL Client Certificates for some custom security related checks.

When debugging the app, `request.GetClientCertificate()` returns `null` for any service call, no matter what I tried so far.

**The Tested Code:**

Basically, on my service's side, I have a method that goes something like this:

```
class CertificateChecker : ICertificateChecker
{
    public bool Check(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var cert = request.GetClientCertificate();
    }
}
```

My unit tests with the client cert attached to the request using `request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.ClientCertificateKey, cert)` pass (the cert comes out exactly as expected, validations work, and so on).

However, when I use a test with an `HttpClient` calling the actual WebAPI app, with the break point set at the `request.GetClientCertificate()` line on service side, the same line returns null.

Here's what I tried:

**Client Certs:**

- Created a fake CA and put it into trusted CA store (tried both LocalMachine and current user).
- Created a Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2) cert signed by that Fake CA and placed it into the Personal store (LocalMachine and Current User).

(basically, followed https://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/ and similar blogs)

On my test that calls the service using `HttpClient`, attached the client cert in the following ways (none of which worked):

- Using `WebRequestHandler` with `ClientCertificateOptions` set to Manual and the cert added to the `ClientCertificates` collection.

  ```
  using (var handler = new WebRequestHandler())
  {
       var cert = GetTestCert();
       handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
       handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

       // and so on...
  }
  ```
- Using the `HttpRequestMessage`, adding the cert as a property with the key set to `HttpPropertyKeys.ClientCertificateKey` (this approach works when unit testing as described above).

  ```
  request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.ClientCertificateKey, cert);
  ```

The `cert` variable is set to the expected `X509Certificate2` object in both cases.

**Hosting:**

- IISExpress: Tried to run the app in IISExpress.

  Edited applicationhost.config with `iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled` set to "true" and the following access settings (neither worked):

  ```
  <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
  <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
  ```
- Local IIS
  Set the web app to run in IIS on my local machine

  - The site in IIS is configured with an HTTPS binding using a trusted certificate.
  - Web app configured to use https protocol with IIS Client Cert mapping authentication enabled.
  - Tried both the access option combinations (`Ssl, SslNegotiateCert` and `SslNegotiateCert`) (via configuration editor)

In both cases, when accessing the web api via the https url using a web browser, I get the index view of the home controller to show without issue (so, the server side cert is trusted).

Answer (score 4):

I know it is a bit old but I was facing the same issue and i solved it by followinfgthis article:

https://improveandrepeat.com/2017/07/how-to-configure-iis-express-to-accept-ssl-client-certificates/

The problem was a configuration on the IIS server, which can be modified also on IIS express. I report it in case the link will not be available.

> For IIS change the server configuration file, for IIS Express modify
>   the file under your solution located in
>   .vs\config\applicationhost.config
>
> Search for an xml element called  inside a  element:
>
> ```
> <security>
>   <access sslFlags="None" />
> ```
>
> The default configuration has no support for SSL client certificates.
>   You need to modify the sslFlags attribute to include these options:
>   Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert
>
> ```
> <security>
>         <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
> ```
>
> The next step is to find the element
>   :
>
> ```
> <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false"></iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
> ```
>
> If you change enabled to true, IIS Express will start accepting client
>   certificates:
>
> ```
> <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true">
>             </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
> ```
>
> You now need to restart Visual Studio and IIS Express. IIS Express can
>   be restarted using the icon in your system tray.
>
> From now on you will be asked for a client certificate and you can
>   debug the whole application inside Visual Studio. This may not look
>   like a big improvement, but trust me, it makes debugging much simpler.

Hope this could help someone else :-)

Answer (score 1):

Great detailed information about your problem.

I'm going to assume the issue is with attaching the client certificate w/ HttpClient, since you cannot view the certificate on the server side in that situation. All of the hosting and server side certificate configuration sounds good.

1. I would make sure that the `X509Certificate2 cert` variable that you are attaching is a public key that exists in your local certificate store (I'm not sure what store location you are storing this in) (you can check using mmc.exe). Also make sure that public key has a private key with it since the HttpClient will need that to sign the requests.
2. In your code snippet you have `using (var handler = new WebRequestHandler())` before the rest of your code. Make sure you are constructing your `HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)` in the using as well or the handler will be disposed.

Otherwise the handler creation looks good.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I do have an exportable private key for the cert in the store (it is in the Personal store on the machine that runs both the service and the test using the `HttpClient`) and I do already use the HttpClient(handler) constructor. I also tried getting the same cert from a pfx (with private key included)--but I get the same result (the correct cert is instantiated, but never makes it to the server side).

Comment: Sounds like the client is constructed correctly. Does the server know what type of client credentials to expect? Typically I use             `HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(hostAddres);`             `config.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;` to configure the server to accept client certificates as credentials.

Comment: I am using IISExpress or local IIS for hosting, so I'm not sure if HttpSelfHostConfiguration would apply? Is there another HttpConfiguration type that has a similar way to configure the credential type for web API hosted in IIS or IISExpress?

Comment: I haven't done it, but the section SSL Client Certificates on this [page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api), looks helpful.

Comment: @dolbomir , I know it was a long time ago but did you had any luck with this? I am exiriencing the very same issue with HttpClient and very simple WebApi2 service

Comment: @dolbomir, I am also having this issue, did someone find how to fix the issue?